# A 'Done' button in the Action Bar?

Tags: android

In the Google Calendar app, there is a 'Done' button in the top right corner

[image]

To reproduce this, is a custom view containing a TextView on the right needed to replace the default on in the ActionBar (using `.setCustomView()`)? If so, would this also replace the existing title, home/back button on the left, etc.? If so, does that mean the custom view will need to include those again?

What is the canonical approach?

Thanks

Comment: you can just inflate menu with "DONE" title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To reproduce this, is a custom view containing a TextView on the right
>   needed to replace the default on in the ActionBar (using
>   .setCustomView())?

why a custom view ? You should be able to achieve the same with

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

the click event is reported to

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

EDIT

```
final MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1000, Menu.NONE, R.string.done);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

Comment: Using `onCreateOptionsMenu`, how do you get the menu to show 'DONE' rather than 3 dots though?

Comment: This will not respect the 16dp padding on the right - correct? If so, is there a way to make it maintain 16dp right padding?

Comment: the way it will be displayed is up to the system and it is strictly bounded to the version of Android.

Answer (score 8):

TooBar, and add menu on it;

1. add `Toolbar` in your layout.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/common_toolbar"
       style="@style/ToolbarShadow"
       />
   ```
2. In your activity:

   ```
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_done, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.action_menu_done:
               // do someing
               break;

       }
   }
   ```
3. create menu(menu_done.xml)

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <item android:id="@+id/action_menu_done"
         android:title="DONE"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_done"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         />

   </menu>
   ```

Comment: Is the 'DONE' supposed to be an icon though? Isn't it plain text? 'DONE' isn't a menu item though - right?

Comment: In this case, both - you can remove the icon, if you don't want it - or leave just the icon. But! `mipmap` is not the right place where to place your drawables. `mipmap` should only contain the app icon.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Doing the above, wouldn't 'DONE' be an item inside the settings menu rather than the menu itself?

Comment: @JohnMunroe Settings menu? Do you mean the SharedPreferences? No.